# Snowflake Window Function - Lag Window Function to Check Distinct User Previous Role

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to use a window function to check what the previous role of a user was. if a new user id is shown, the sequence restarts the count BUT previous role doesnt start at null. It just carries over the role from the previous USERID. Any thoughts on how I can get the first record to start as NULL? Previous Role would be null as its the first record that shows. *(Note not displayed in output, but records are ordered by Account_Date_created)*

Based on my sql attempt,

```
SELECT
    USER_ID
   , ACCOUNT
   , row_number() over (partition by USER_ID order by account_date_created ) as seq
   , ROLE as CURRENT_ROW
   , lag(role) over (order by USER_ID, ACCOUNT, seq)  as prev_Role

from Table;
```

**Current output based on above SQL**

```
USERID  ACCOUNT   SEQ   Current Role  Prev ROLE 
222     12863r6     1   Owner         NULL
222     12871r9     2   Owner         Owner
222     14142rr1    3   Owner         Owner
333     2563r013    1   Owner         Owner
333     36998r64    2   Admin         Owner
333     37001r05    3   Owner         Admin
333     37016r10    4   Owner         Owner
```

**Desired output**

```
USERID  ACCOUNT SEQ Current Role    Prev Role
222     12863r6     1   Owner       NULL
222     12871r9     2   Owner        Owner
222     14142rr1    3   Owner        Owner
333     2563r013    1   Owner       NULL
333     36998r64    2   Admin        Owner
333     37001r05    3   Owner        Admin
333     37016r10    4   Owner        Owner
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not have a partition by clause in the second window function, so it's forming a single window that spans the entire table. You want to partition by USER_ID and then order by account_date_created:

```
SELECT
    USER_ID
   , ACCOUNT
   , row_number() over (partition by USER_ID order by account_date_created ) as seq
   , ROLE as CURRENT_ROW
   , lag(role) over (partition by USER_ID order by account_date_created)  as prev_Role

from Table;
```